# Multiple mysql counts from order table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an order table that looks like the below

```
order_id  ordered    checkin    collected   
======================================
1           2           1           4       
2           4           2           4       
3           4           2           4       
4           1           4           1
```

This represents which member of staff ordered, checked in and collected each order.

I would like to perform a sql query which counts how many orders, checkins and collections each member of staff has made. This would also JOIN to the staff table which outputs the staff members name for each row

So for staff member 1 (John), it would be 1 order, 1 checkin and 1 collected.
Staff member 2 (Simon) would be 1 orders, 2 checkin and 0 collections and so on for the other members of staff.

What would be the best mysql query to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** You can calculate row counts per staff id for each column individually and then join with staff table using outer join.

```
SELECT s.id, s.name, 
       COALESCE(o.ordered,   0) ordered, 
       COALESCE(c.checkin,   0) checkin, 
       COALESCE(l.collected, 0) collected
  FROM staff s LEFT JOIN 
(
  SELECT ordered id, COUNT(*) ordered
    FROM orders
-- WHERE ordered_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
--   AND ordered_date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   GROUP BY ordered
) o ON s.id = o.id LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT checkin id, COUNT(*) checkin
    FROM orders
-- WHERE checkin_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
--   AND checkin_date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   GROUP BY checkin
) c ON s.id = c.id LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT collected id, COUNT(*) collected
    FROM orders
-- WHERE collected_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
--   AND collected_date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
   GROUP BY collected
) l ON s.id = l.id
```

or you can take a different approach unpivoting `orders` table first and then conditionally aggregating it by staff id and again join it with staff table using outer join

```
SELECT s.id, s.name,
       COALESCE(p.ordered,   0) ordered, 
       COALESCE(p.checkin,   0) checkin, 
       COALESCE(p.collected, 0) collected
  FROM staff s LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT id, 
         SUM(type = 1) ordered,
         SUM(type = 2) checkin,
         SUM(type = 3) collected
    FROM
  (
    SELECT type,
           CASE type 
             WHEN 1 THEN ordered 
             WHEN 2 THEN checkin
             WHEN 3 THEN collected
           END id
      FROM orders CROSS JOIN
    (
      SELECT 1 type UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3
    ) n
--   WHERE (ordered_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
--     AND  ordered_date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
--      OR (checkin_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
--     AND  checkin_date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
--      OR (collected_date >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
--     AND  collected_date <= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
  ) u
   GROUP BY id
) p
    ON s.id = p.id
```

*Based on your comments queries has been updated with sample `WHERE` clauses to filter only rows for previous month*

Sample output:

```
| ID |  NAME | ORDERED | CHECKIN | COLLECTED |
|----|-------|---------|---------|-----------|
|  1 |  John |       1 |       1 |         1 |
|  2 | Simon |       1 |       2 |         0 |
|  3 |  Mark |       0 |       0 |         0 |
|  4 | Helen |       2 |       1 |         3 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e161d/11)** demo

Comment: @dgj Did it help? Do you need more help with your question?

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry for the slow reply. I've been working on a lot of things and just came back to this. Your answer looks perfect, I never would have figured it out. It's a surprisingly complicated answer for what seems like would be a easy query. I'm also collecting timestamps for when items are ordered, checked in, collected. Where would each of the WHERE clauses go in?

Comment: ^If say I was doing staff performance in the last week / month etc.

Comment: @dgj The complications come from the fact that you store these indicators in a pivoted form along with orders. If you were to store this data in a separate table with a schema like (id, user_id, order_id, indicator, timestamp) it would be easier and more flexible to query. Anyway I updated the answer to show how to incorporate WHERE clauses to filter data.

Comment: update: got this working perfectly, including with the WHERE clauses. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(*)` to count all orders in your table. Also Use `COUNT(checkin)` `COUNT(collected)`  to count the other fields.

If  you are trying to get the counts for one user, you can user `WHERE` to do it.

```
SELECT
  COUNT(order_id) AS   order_count,
  COUNT(checking) AS chcekin_count,
  COUNT(collected) AS collected_count
FROM
  your table
  WHERE staff_member = idOfStaff
```

ALSO you can perform many counts from your table and collect it as one table

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM table WHERE staff = ?)   AS staff_1_order_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(order_id) FROM table WHERE staff = ?)   AS staff_2_order_count
```

Answer (score 0):

peterm's answer is correct. Code below is essentially the same without the 'staff' table.  Use COALESCE, as peterm showed.  The important bit is to do the outer join, not an inner join, so counts of 0 still show up in your report.

```
select T1.member,T1.ordered_count,T2.checkin_count, collected_count
from (
    select ordered as "member", count(*) as "ordered_count"
    from orders group by ordered
) as T1
left join  (
    select checkin as "member", count(*) as "checkin_count"
    from orders
    group by checkin
) as T2 on T1.member=T2.member
left join  (
    select collected as "member", count(*) as "collected_count"
    from orders
    group by collected
) as T3 on T2.member=T3.member;
```